# Pyqtgraph Put the Selected Region of Interest in a Different Color Map

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqtgraph, colormap

Here is a snippet of code slightly modified from one of pyqtgraph examples :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pyqtgraph as pg

pg.setConfigOptions(imageAxisOrder='row-major')

## Create image to display
image = cv2.imread('panda.jpg')

#Transpose the image
def picturetranspose(picture):
    shape = picture.shape
    result = np.empty((shape[1],shape[0],shape[2]),dtype= np.uint8)
    for i in range(0,3):
        result[:,:,i] = np.transpose(picture[:,:,i])
    return result
    
arr = np.rot90(picturetranspose(image))
#arr = cv2.applyColorMap(arr, cv2.COLORMAP_JET)

app = pg.mkQApp("ROI Examples")
w = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(show=True, size=(1000,800), border=True)
w.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: ROI Examples')

w1 = w.addLayout(row=0, col=0)
v1a = w1.addViewBox(row=1, col=0, lockAspect=True)
v1b = w1.addViewBox(row=2, col=0, lockAspect=True)
img1a = pg.ImageItem(arr)
v1a.addItem(img1a)
img1b = pg.ImageItem()
v1b.addItem(img1b)

rois = []
rois.append(pg.PolyLineROI([[80, 60], [90, 30], [60, 40]], pen=(6,9), closed=True))

def update(roi):
    img1b.setImage(roi.getArrayRegion(arr, img1a), levels=(0, arr.max()))
    
for roi in rois:
    roi.sigRegionChanged.connect(update)
    v1a.addItem(roi)

update(rois[-1])
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.exec()
```

Here the image "panda.jpg" is given by:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ejY0CjfEwS6SGS2qe_uRX2JvlruMKvPX?usp=sharing.

Running the above code and moving the ROI (Region of Interest) a little bit will give:

[image]

This is all working fine. What I want to do now is to make the selected ROI into a different colormap. My attemps are as follows: if I add the line `arr = cv2.applyColorMap(arr, cv2.COLORMAP_JET)` right after the definition of `arr`, then what I will get is:
[image]

This successfully converts the colorspace but not  in the way I want because I need only the selected region to be in the new colormap . My next attempt is to write `img1b.setImage(cv2.applyColorMap(roi.getArrayRegion(arr, img1a), cv2.COLORMAP_JET), levels=(0, arr.max()))` in place of `img1b.setImage(roi.getArrayRegion(arr, img1a), levels=(0, arr.max()))`. But this leads to an error message:

[image]

How should I proceed ?

Edit:
By writing `arr2 = cv2.applyColorMap(arr, cv2.COLORMAP_JET)` and writing `img1b.setImage(roi.getArrayRegion(arr2, img1a), levels=(0, arr.max()))` in place of `img1b.setImage(roi.getArrayRegion(arr, img1a), levels=(0, arr.max()))`, I am able to get the following:

[image]

All I still need now is to make the selected region (which I label in red) in the different color map. It is perferred that exactly the selected region being in different color map rather than the bounding rectangle.

Edit:
In the end, I resolved my problem by replacing my `update` method with the following:

```
def update(roi):
    arr_copy = arr.copy()
    
    slices, tr = roi.getArraySlice(arr, img1a, returnSlice=True)
    
    colormapped = roi.getArrayRegion(arr2, img1a)
    
    newslices = (slice(slices[0].start, slices[0].start + colormapped.shape[0], None),
                 slice(slices[1].start, slices[1].start + colormapped.shape[1], None),
                 slice(None,None,None))
    
    gray_original = np.dot(arr_copy[newslices][...,:3], [0.299, 0.587, 0.114])
    gray_colormapped = np.dot(colormapped[...,:3], [0.299, 0.587, 0.114])
    gray_original_masked = ma.array(gray_original,mask = gray_colormapped).filled(fill_value = 0)
    
    complement = np.empty(gray_original_masked.shape)
    complement[gray_original_masked == 0] = 1
    complement[gray_original_masked != 0] = 0
    
    interior_croped_0 = ma.array(arr_copy[newslices][:,:,0],mask = complement).filled(fill_value = 0)
    interior_croped_1 = ma.array(arr_copy[newslices][:,:,1],mask = complement).filled(fill_value = 0)
    interior_croped_2 = ma.array(arr_copy[newslices][:,:,2],mask = complement).filled(fill_value = 0)
    
    original_color_masked = np.empty(arr_copy[newslices].shape)
    original_color_masked[:,:,0] = interior_croped_0
    original_color_masked[:,:,1] = interior_croped_1
    original_color_masked[:,:,2] = interior_croped_2
    
    final = original_color_masked + colormapped 
    arr_copy[newslices] = final
    
    img1a.setImage(arr_copy, levels=(0, arr.max()))
```

[image]

I thank D Malan for giving me the hint about using slices.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Seeking recommendations for libraries is explicitly [off-topic](/help/on-topic) here. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Once you have done some research from other sources, made an attempt, if you get stuck and ask a specific question, we can help you. As it stands, your question is too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the slices in the original array which you need to update using [`getArraySlice`](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graphicsItems/roi.html?highlight=getArrayRegion#pyqtgraph.ROI.getArraySlice).

Change your `update` method to:

```
arr2 = cv2.applyColorMap(arr, cv2.COLORMAP_JET)

def update(roi):
    img1b.setImage(roi.getArrayRegion(arr, img1a), levels=(0, arr.max()))

    # Get a copy of the original array that can be modified
    arr_copy = arr.copy()
    # Get the slices of the ROI
    slices, tr = roi.getArraySlice(arr, img1a, returnSlice=True)
    # Update the slices to have the values of the colourmap
    arr_copy[slices] = arr2[slices]
    # Update the image with the new values
    img1a.setImage(arr_copy, levels=(0, arr.max()))
```

[image: Panda with updated colourmap]

Comment: Thank you very much for responding! This is brilliant and is almost what I want. Is it possible to make the second color map display at exactly the pixels that is inside the ROI, instead of the bounding rectangle of ROI?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. Only the inside of the ROI and not the outside line?

Comment: See the `screen` image in https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ejY0CjfEwS6SGS2qe_uRX2JvlruMKvPX. The result of your code applies the color map to the bounding rectangle as well. Is it possible to apply the colormap to only the interior of the ROI?

Comment: Well done for figuring it out!